# How to simulate properly UWP app restart in Visual Studio in order to simulate crash?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, uwp, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have a really tricky problem and I can't find out how to solve it.

I created a UWP app with notification feature, saving all the data into .txt files in the App's LocalFolder.

The problem is that, when the UWP creates succesfully a notification schedule (saving all the notification data into this .txt file correctly)... the app just crashes when restarting it!

The most strange thing is that if I try to rerun the app itself by recompiling from VS, it doesn't crash... but it can't get data saved in that .txt file yet.

So, I was wondering how to simulate app restart in VS 2017, without needing to interrupt the debugger, as I need it to find out this problem that's making me crazy.

Thank you all for the attention.

Best regards.

Comment: "Suspend and shutdown" and then launch again from VS should do it, no?

Comment: can you specify what you are doing on load of the application (that is the first thing the application does when it loads) ? are you checking if the txt file exists or some other logic ?

Comment: A more simple way should be view the app start logs. Open your Event Viewer from cortona's window,then go to Applications and Service logs->Microsoft->Windows->Apps->Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Optional. The logs there are the app start log, which can show you more info.